# Why does the while loop only end when I close the tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a big problem with my code. I am a beginner and trying to program a vocabulary trainer with a gui but im already failing. I know my code is probably very bad but I am trying to understand the problem. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


vocabulary = []
translations = []
finished1 = False
finished2 = False

root = tk.Tk()


def savevocabulary():
    vocabulary.append(vocabularyinput)
    pleaseinputvocab.pack_forget()
    vocabularyEntry.pack_forget()
    vocabularyButton.pack_forget()
    global finished1
    finished1 = True


def savetranslations():
    translations.append(translationinput)
    pleaseinputtrans.pack_forget()
    translationEntry.pack_forget()
    translationButton.pack_forget()
    global finished2
    finished2 = True


def askingquestion():
    whatis = tk.Label(root, text="What is " + vocabulary[0].get() + "in English?")
    whatis.pack()
    whatisinput = tk.StringVar()
    whatisentry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=whatisinput)
    whatisentry.pack()
    if whatisinput == translations[0]:
        correct = tk.Label(root, text="Correct!")
        correct.pack()
    else:
        false = tk. Label(root, text="False!")
        false.pack()


while finished1 is False and finished2 is False:

    pleaseinputvocab = tk.Label(root, text="Please enter a vocabulary into the field and then click Done")
    pleaseinputvocab.pack()
    vocabularyinput = tk.StringVar()
    vocabularyEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=vocabularyinput)
    vocabularyEntry.pack()
    vocabularyButton = tk.Button(root, text="Done", command=savevocabulary)
    vocabularyButton.pack()

    pleaseinputtrans = tk.Label(root, text="Please enter the translation into the field and then click Done")
    pleaseinputtrans.pack()
    translationinput = tk.StringVar()
    translationEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=translationinput)
    translationEntry.pack()
    translationButton = tk.Button(root, text="Done", command=savetranslations)
    translationButton.pack()
    root.mainloop()

askingquestion()

root.mainloop()
```

When I start the program then the i can fill in the a vocabulary and a translation but then the widgets should disappear and I should be asked to fill in the translation to the vocabulary. Instead nothing is happening and when I close the window, this message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maxig\Documents\ll.py", line 63, in <module>
    askingquestion()
  File "C:\Users\maxig\Documents\ll.py", line 31, in askingquestion
    whatis = tk.Label(root, text="What is " + vocabulary[0].get() + "in English?")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3148, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed
```

That means that the function is called after the window is closed. Why is that the case?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. tkinter label is missing, please review and accept my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not what it seems. The issue is not your while loop but `root.mainloop()`. This creates a loop inside the function which needs to be running until you close the window; that's how tkinter works.

You can instead call `askingquestion()` when the user clicks a button.

```
pleaseinputvocab = tk.Label(root, text="Please enter a vocabulary into the field and then click Done")
pleaseinputvocab.pack()
vocabularyinput = tk.StringVar()
vocabularyEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=vocabularyinput)
vocabularyEntry.pack()
vocabularyButton = tk.Button(root, text="Done", command=savevocabulary)
vocabularyButton.pack()

pleaseinputtrans = tk.Label(root, text="Please enter the translation into the field and then click Done")
pleaseinputtrans.pack()
translationinput = tk.StringVar()
translationEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=translationinput)
translationEntry.pack()
translationButton = tk.Button(root, text="Done", command=savetranslations)
translationButton.pack()

ask_button = tk.Button(root, text="Ask question", command=askingquestion)
ask_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also, in Python, variable names should follow the naming convention. Instead of `translationButton`, `translation_button`.